# Modify search result (Display Suite search)

Tags: theming, search, display-suite

Second day and I don't see solution for my problem. 
I want to modify the output of a single search result. 
Yesterday, after ~8h (?) I understood that `search-api-page-results.tpl.php` overrides default search result**s** page. But `search-api-page-result.tpl.php` doesn't overrides single search result. The same `search-result.tpl.php`. Also tried `template_preprocess_search_result` function with no response. 
I know that I can modify output of result in *Structure > Display Suite > Manage Display* but this is not enough for what I want to do next with output. 
Cache ofc cleared many times. 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: you can copy these templates files in your current active theme directory and override theme as per your requirements.

Comment: @WaQaRAli I know that, it doesn't work

Comment: firstly don't use any extra module for override search result. Just try did with core search as said in my above comment. This is suggestion to check either templates are working right or not.

Comment: you can check this question. May be it will help you. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159198/how-to-make-custom-template-for-search-results